Ubuntu 24.04 GNOME menu, some icons and options not shown
I upgrade my 22.04 to 24.04.At the end - some gnome menu icons and selections not shown.
Any idea or solution?


The menu on code updated at 09 June 24 looked like this:

After dist-upgrading at 06 Sept 24 it looks the same. So I must assume you've installed a "tweak" or a gnome shell addon that is not compatible anymore.
The result was independent of any themes, so you've must've changed something or the "upgrade" from 22.04 to 24.04 was broken.

When  I plug out ethernet and then restart PC, I see all options well. And plug in network and enable it. I check it doubles. I plug in network and restart PC again same issue occurs
